# How do I connect lambda --> RDS postgres DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

I created an image of my node aplication that is going to update a value in the database.  The image is in lambda. On cloud9, the function works without problems but when I trigger it with SQS the function is executed (logs) but the value is not updated in the database. I suspect the lambda does not have access to the RDS. How do I fix it? I use PG to connect to the DB with variables entered in lambda

I have already changed the VPC but no result ,How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the AWS Lambda function connected to the same VPC as the Amazon RDS database? What is the configuration of the Security Group on the Lambda function (Outbound rules) and the RDS database (inbound rules)? What error message are you receiving when attempting to connect?

Comment: Yes, same VPC and inbound and outbound I have temporarily to test all protocols allowed and from ipv4 allowed.

Comment: You need to figure out whether the Lambda function is connecting to the database by adding debugging information. For example, try a SELECT and see whether it has a result. It could be as simple as requiring a COMMIT after the INSERT, but the first step is to determine where the problem lies (connectivity or database).